# Intent Filter for handling address press in Contact?

Tags: android, filter, dictionary, android-intent, contacts

Folks, when viewing a contact, you can press on the address to view that address in a map application (such as Google Maps or VZW Navigator). I would like define an intent-filter such that my app will show up in the list of apps that can handle said intent. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

From logcat, I see the following from ActivityManager:

```
Starting activity: 
Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/6792 cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity }
```

I've tried a several combinations of intent-filters, e.g.:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name=”android.intent.action.View” />
  <category android:name=”android.intent.category.DEFAULT” />
  <category android:name=”android.intent.category.BROWSABLE” />
  <data android:scheme=”geo” />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
  <action android:name=”android.intent.action.View” />
  <category android:name=”android.intent.category.DEFAULT” />
  <category android:name=”android.intent.category.BROWSABLE” />
  <data android:scheme=”content” android:host=”com.android.contacts” android:pathPattern=”/data/*” />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, provided by Google Developer Relations is:

```
<intent-filter android:label="MyApp">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address_v2" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: this one does *not work* on my Android 4.2.2 phone (Galaxy S4)

Answer (score 3):

in ICS you should use this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="geo" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The received intent should be handled accordingly (diffrently).
please note that on ICS and with this intent-filter you don't need a special permission to read contact address.

Answer (score 1):

for early versions of Android I used

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/*" android:host="com.android.contacts" android:pathPrefix="/data" android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

`VIEW` is supposed to be capitalized. Yours is not.

Comment: Thanks, my typo above was an obvious mistake...still did not work.