# Replace stock address book in Android

Tags: android, contacts, addressbook

I'm developing a Contacts Manager for Android and my goal is to replace the standard one. I have been looking for the appropriate intent without success.

Is there an Intent for it? Or Google doesn't allow to replace?

regards and thanks in advance,
Rafael Muñoz

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an intent-filter.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890797/intent-filter-for-handling-address-press-in-contact) is an example on StackOverflow that you should be able to modify to make work for you.

Comment: I know about intent-filter. But I don't know is if there is a intent for the Contacts Manager and if there is, which one is it.